# jQuery function to execute when I leave a form

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want jQuery function to execute when I leave a form to the upper part of the browser, other browsers, other windows, taskbar or desktop.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {   
        $(".myform").on('mouseleave', function () {
                $("#<%= Button1.ClientID%>").trigger('click');
        });
     });

     <form runat="server" class="myform">
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this- users move their mice in all sorts of crazy ways and this behavior is likely to cause frustration and annoyance for users.

Here is the jQuery for what you are trying to do:

```
$(function () {   
    $(".myform").on('mouseleave', function () {
        /* Some function goes here */
    });
});
```

If you want this to occur when the user leaves the content of the browser window, replace:

```
$(".myform").on("mouseleave"...
```

with

$("body").on("mouseleave"...

And the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/s9S6R/1/

Comment: Hello , he wants to leave form when scroll down,Not to submit form

Comment: Gotcha. I totally read that wrong. I should go to bed now. Hahaha.

Comment: Edited to better answer the intent of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fire the event when the user **moves the mouse out** of your form, you can use -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#frmMain').mouseleave(function(){
        alert('Hello, you went outside form');
    });
});
```

Check here - http://jsfiddle.net/5tKA6/

But if you want to do it for the whole browser, then -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('document').mouseleave(function(){
        alert('Hello, you went outside form');
    });
});
```

Check here - http://jsfiddle.net/5tKA6/2/